# Use JQuery Scroll to Fade/Scale Divs In/Out

Tags: jquery

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHguL/)**

I decided to redesign my website today by adding some scrolling effects via JQuery+CSS3.
I have a set of divs centered horizontally and spaced a bit vertically.

I'm trying to apply [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JZWRA/) effect so each `div` will fade/scale in when scrolled and fade/scale out while fading/scaling another in.

I know I can use the [`.scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler, but not sure how it would be used for this type of effect.

Here's the current jQuery added at time of posting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container").scroll(function() {
        if ($(".container").scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".container div").css('background', 'rgb(200, 54, 54)').stop().animate({"opacity":".5"}, 1000)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be a useful script for you , just not to recreate the wheel:
http://www.bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/

```
$.scrollIt({
  upKey: 38,             // key code to navigate to the next section
  downKey: 40,           // key code to navigate to the previous section
  easing: 'linear',      // the easing function for animation
  scrollTime: 600,       // how long (in ms) the animation takes
  activeClass: 'active', // class given to the active nav element
  onPageChange: null,    // function(pageIndex) that is called when page is changed
  topOffset: 0           // offste (in px) for fixed top navigation
});
```

it will automatically detect active element shown on monitor , then you can trigger any action upon activation of elemnt ( element has been scrolled to ).

just in case you want a native solution then use this upon scrolling your container :

http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html

```
if($('#element').visible();) {//do whatever you want}
```

and here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/AHguL/8/

Finally if you are searching really cool scroll effect , this will be a perfect choice:
http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Comment: That plugin is amazing!